# Why do other people's profile pictures look like this, instead of their Steam profile pictures?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

[image: CS:GO profile pictures]

Other people's profile pictures look like this in *CS:GO*. This is on games, in the menu screen, and everywhere else in *CS:GO* but not in Steam, why is this? I expect people's profile pictures to look like their Steam profile pictures, but everyone's profile pictures look like the ones pictured.

Comment: How would you expect it to look?

Comment: I expect people's profile pictures to look like their Steam profile pictures, but everyone's profile pictures look like the ones pictured.

Answer (score 3):

This is an option called "Hide Avatar Images" in the settings.

Set it to "Show All".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but this should do the trick as I suspect problems with your Steam or game installation.

#### 1. Re-assign firewall rules

- close Steam

Remove the following executables from your Windows firewall list, if present.

- steaminstall.exe
- steam.exe
- hl.exe
- hl2.exe
- steamTmp.exe

Easiest way to access that is by pressing the Windows key and typing "allow". It should open the search and already suggest the right option.

[image]

When you have done so you can start Steam and when prompted allow firewall access. Don't start the game yet.

#### 2. Verify integrity of CS:GO

- right-click CS:GO in your Steam library and click *Properties*
- in the pop-up go to *Local files* and click on *Verify integrity of game files...*

[image]

Start your game and allow firewall access again when prompted. This should hopefully fix your issue.

#### 3. If that still does not help you can try re-installing CS:GO as a last resort.

- make a backup of your CS:GO folder just in case
- delete your CS:GO folder
- then download it from Steam again

You can easily find the game folder by following the step above. Instead of clicking on Verify you just have to click *Browse* on top of the pop-up and Steam will lead you right where it is.

Comment: You think those icons being as they are is a technical problem? I assumed it was just how CS:GO handles the icons, maybe to make them more neutral.

Comment: @Joachim I've never seen that in any public game and especially not in a lobby. It *may* be possible that some censorship has happened here, but I've never seen it (as a day one Steam user). I suspect problems with the CDN or network as avatars are stored on a different network than the game lobby. The icons shown are just default placeholders, just like we have here on SE.

Comment: It is not a technical problem, but a setting so you don't have to see other player's Steam avatars, which is especially useful for streamers.